# oil contract -- meaning

Tags: meaning

Source: [Russian ruble collapses to 7-month low on weak oil prices](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/russian-ruble-collapses-7-month-081343086.html)

Given the following context, what exactly is an *oil contract*?

> Oil is the backbone of the Russian economy and the fall of the ruble follows a sharp decline in the price of crude. The U.S. **oil contract** on Friday dropped below $40 per barrel for the first time since 2009 and on Monday was down another $1.23 a barrel at $39.22.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question concerns a financial term in context, and is not related to learning English (it does not ask what a contract is or what oil is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no economist, but I'd say almost certainly OP's context is referring to...

> *the **benchmark U.S. oil contract,** known as West Texas Intermediate, and the European benchmark, known as Brent.* [<sub><sup>(Source)</sup></sub>](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052702304543904577398703963203654)

In the UK we rarely hear reference to *[the US] oil contract* - our financial news stories usually say [***Brent*** [crude] dropped to [some new low price]](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brent%20crude%20dropped%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

You could assume a "deleted" word such as ***price*** or ***index*** after ***contract*** if that helps parsing.

Presumably the WTI and Brent "benchmark prices" are effectively some kind of "average", and some specific authority is responsible for determining the actual value in "real time" (since tiny adjustments would potentially have *huge* implications for financial "oil futures contracts", where the actual price to be paid/received is often specified relative to the benchmark *at time of delivery*, rather than *when the deal was struck*). But that's outside the scope of ELL (and as implied, I don't know who controls it).

Comment: +1 Perzackly, but the price is for a 'standard' contract, not an 'average', and the *US* here has to refer not to the price of US oil in the US but to the price on the US market of 'international' oil.

Comment: @StoneyB: I haven't bothered to look up the details of the implementation, but I assume it's something like [the LIBOR rate](http://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/libor/libor.aspx). They're both "standard" values that are effectively arrived at by some kind of algorithmic "averaging" process, as opposed to, say, the Bank of England's "base rate", which is unilaterally ***set*** by the relevant authority, rather than being "calculated".

Comment: It's a straight market price for a futures contract, just like the price of shares. What's quoted at any given moment is the price on the most recent transaction, so it runs up and down all day during market hours.

Comment: @StoneyB: But any *given* futures contract is normally due for settlement *on some specific date*. Surely if (today) I "undertake to buy" 5,000 bushels of Yellow Soybean next month, and you do do the same - but with *your* contract not due until next year, we're likely to pay different amounts. It's all explained [here](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/102314/understanding-benchmark-oils-brent-blend-wti-and-dubai.asp), but my eyes kinda glazed over after the first couple of pages. It's a "price", Jim, but not as we know it.

Comment: Yes: contracts are sold for a specific month/year, each with a different price. Commodity producers and users 'hedge' their future prices with current sales; speculators gamble on a future rise or fall. In effect, the producers and users sell the risk to speculators.

Comment: @StoneyB: I imagine some of the more "bullish" speculators involved in the futures market are catching a *serious* cold this week! :)

Answer (score 3):

Transactions on commodity markets do not involve actual physical commodities such as crude oil, hard red winter wheat, soybeans, pork bellies, and the like but standardized 'contracts': promises to deliver a standard quantity of a standard commodity to a standard location on a standard future date.

The Rules of each market define the contract standards. On the Chicago Board of Trade (CBOT), for instance, a soybean contract is for 5,000 bushels of Yellow Soybeans. The 'contract' in your quote is a New York Mercantile Exchange (NYMEX) contract for 1,000 barrels of Brent crude oil, the international benchmark for oil prices. These contracts are sold for various future months at various prices, and the price is adjusted for variation in quality and place of delivery in the comparatively few cases when the contract ends in physical  delivery.

Answer (score -1):

A "contract" is a deal between two people or organizations. Usually a contract involves one side buying something from the other. This could be as simple as "I will buy X from you for Y dollars", or it could involve all sorts of complexities about conditions, schedules, etc. (You can have a contract that doesn't involve any money changing hands, but that's not the point here.)

An "oil contract" is a contract to buy oil. In this case, apparently the U.S. has a contract to buy oil from Russia.

Comment: I don't think they meant any particular contract by US to buy oil from Russia.  It's the price on the commodities market for "US crude oil" (at which refineries buy it from companies who extract oil).

Comment: @VictorBazarov Could be. I followed the link and read the article and it wasn't clear to me whether this was talking about one specific contract or some more general "contract price" or what.

Comment: @Jay the sentence says "*The* U.S. oil contract". There are thousands (maybe millions) of individual contracts to buy and sell oil made every day, so it doesn't make sense to talk about one specific contract without explaining what it was, or why it was newsworthy. "The oil contract" is the same type of expression as "The Dow [Jones Index]" - i.e., a measure of the "average" market price expressed as a single number.

Comment: I'm well aware that there are many contracts for any given commodity. The wording of the paragraph led me to believe they were referring to one particularly large and important contract. FumbleFingers answer makes sense on this point -- that it's probably referring to some benchmark price and is leaving out key words.